# Setting jquery datepicker in modal to event start and end date (FullCalendar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, bootstrap-modal

By clicking on an event in my calendar, a modal window opens with form fields for start and end date with jquery datepicker. I can display the event dates with `<p class="start">Start At: <span></span></p>` in the modal window but I can't manage how to set the datepicker initially with these dates.

If this is bad practise I would like to know how to do this better, maybe by using the controller?

From my calendar config in the view:

```
      eventClick: function(info,event){
        $('#processName').html(info.event.title + " (" + info.event.extendedProps.eventId + ")");
        $('.start').html(info.event.start);
        $('.end').html(info.event.end);
        $('#eventName').html('eventName');
        $('#editAssignmentModal').modal();
     
      },
```

From modal window html:

```
<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mymodal" name="start" value="">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<p class="start">Start At: <span></span></p>
```

Comment: Is `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="mymodal" name="start" value="">` the one with the datepicker? If so then try `$("#mymodal").val(info.event.start);`

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Make it an answer, so I can give you the credits. By the way: Is there a quick way in JavaScript to convert a date like "Mon Jun 29 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)" to "29.06.2020"?

Comment: If I was you I'd wrap the "start" value in a momentJS object and then use moment's format() function to output the format you need. See http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the value of your input field something like this:

```
$("#mymodal").val(info.event.start);
```

Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/val/